# Power and ground plane layer

Tags: altium, pcb-layers, polygon

I defined PWR and GND layers as planes in layer stack manager. When I want to draw polygon in PWR or GND layer, a placed polygon looks disabled as in the picture.  How can I enable the placed polygon plane in Altium Designer?

[image]

Comment: what tool are you using? Eagle, KiCAD, ... ?

Comment: I am sorry . I am using Altium Designer

Comment: I’m not an Altium expert but I think that if you define a layer as a plane then you don’t need to draw a polygon, you’ll get the full area of the PCB less any keep-outs or apertures for vias on different nets.  Check the gerbers to be certain.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify a layer as a plane, it changes how that layer behaves:

> Power planes are created in the negative. Objects placed on the power plane layer become voids in the copper; the remaining regions will become solid copper.

Thus, when you place a polygon on a layer defined as a plane, you're actually creating an area where no copper should be present.

For more information, see [Defining & Managing Copper Areas for a PCB in Altium Designer](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/defining-and-managing-copper-areas-ad).